# Is possible to serve a dash app on a flask Restful endpoint?

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, flask-restful

I've built a flask REST API that has several endpoints that communicate with a front-end. Everything is working until now so I would like to add a new endpoint to serve a dash application. Precisely I would like to add an `<iframe src="my-backend-endpoint">` to my front-end that calls an endpoint on my backend.
Searching on documentation I see that this is possible using a plain flask app, is it also possible to serve a dash application with a restful API?  How should I build the endpoint to return a dash application?

Answer (score -1):

According to the source code of class Dash and the default parameter server Flask is used as default server. with the current architect, there is no easy way to decouple Flask in dash.py . ...